# Get value data form selected day from syncfution calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, mobile, calendar

I want if we press a certain day on the syncfusion calendar then the text will automatically set the day that was clicked on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO4uW.png)

Here is the code I'm using the `Syncfusion Calendar` in Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/App/Config/palette.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/Icon/dbicons.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/Widgets/dialog_loading.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/Screens/XemTKB/TKBTheoNgay/tkbngay_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/meeting.dart';
import 'package:myhumgupdate/giangvien/models/meetingdata_source.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

class TKBNgay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TKBNgayState createState() => _TKBNgayState();
}

class _TKBNgayState extends State<TKBNgay> {
  List<DateTime> _blackoutDates = <DateTime>[];
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  CalendarDataSource _calendarDataSource;
  dynamic scheduleViewBuilder;
  bool _showDatePickerButton = true;
  bool _allowViewNavigation = true;
  bool _showLeadingAndTrailingDates = true;
  DateTime _minDate;
  DateTime _maxDate;
  final List<CalendarView> _allowedViews = <CalendarView>[
    CalendarView.day,
    CalendarView.week,
    CalendarView.workWeek,
    CalendarView.month,
    CalendarView.schedule
  ];
  ViewChangedCallback viewChangedCallback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<TKBNgayViewModel>.reactive(
        onModelReady: (model) => Future.delayed(Duration.zero,
            () => DialogLoading.show(context, model.getTkbNgay(model.timeNow))),
        builder: (context, model, child) => Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: SfCalendar(
                    controller: _calendarController,
                    dataSource: MeetingDataSource(model.getDataSource),
                    scheduleViewMonthHeaderBuilder: scheduleViewBuilder,
                    appointmentTimeTextFormat: 'hh:mm:ss a',
                    initialDisplayDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year,
                        DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day, 00, 45, 0),
                    allowedViews: _allowedViews,
                    showDatePickerButton: _showDatePickerButton,
                    allowViewNavigation: _allowViewNavigation,
                    onViewChanged: viewChangedCallback,
                    blackoutDates: _blackoutDates,
                    minDate: _minDate,
                    maxDate: _maxDate,
                    monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                        appointmentDisplayMode:
                            MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment,
                        showTrailingAndLeadingDates:
                            _showLeadingAndTrailingDates,
                        appointmentDisplayCount: 4),
                    // timeSlotViewSettings: const TimeSlotViewSettings(
                    //     minimumAppointmentDuration: Duration(minutes: 60)),
                    timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
                      startHour: 0,
                      endHour: 16,
                      timeFormat: " H",
                      timeIntervalHeight: 60,
                      timeTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        viewModelBuilder: () => TKBNgayViewModel());
  }
}
```

Can somebody give me some idea about it? I can't find any event like onDaySelected in `TableCalendar` or onDayAddedOrRemoved in `SmartCalendar`

Answer (score 1):

Get the tapped date details in the calendar - when a date is selected on the header date range picker you can get the selected date details in the onViewChanged callback of the calendar.  Also, when a calendar cell is tapped the selected date details can get through the onTap callback of the calendar.

**Refer:** https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/callbacks

Some KBs might be helpful

1. https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11026/how-to-get-visible-dates-details-from-the-flutter-calendar
2. https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10997/how-to-add-custom-header-and-view-header-in-the-flutter-calendar
3. https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10998/how-to-get-datetime-details-while-tapping-the-flutter-calendar
4. https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12551/how-to-get-the-selected-dates-using-selection-changed-callback-in-the-flutter-calendar